# Errors on upgrade CakePHP 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: cakephp

To access some of the new caching features in Cake, I've been trying to upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3. As recommended, I replaced the lib/Cake folder with the upgraded platform. However, it's throwing a bunch of errors about core controllers that cannot be found.

```
2012-12-19 19:55:11 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ThemeController could not be found.
```

For example:

```
#0 /Users/work/Dropbox/Websites/cake-cart/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-12-19 19:55:11 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ThemeController could not be found.
#0 /Users/work/Dropbox/Websites/cake-cart/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-12-19 19:55:11 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class JsController could not be found.
#0 /Users/work/Dropbox/Websites/cake-cart/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-12-19 19:55:12 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
#0 /Users/work/Dropbox/Websites/cake-cart/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-12-19 19:55:12 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImgController could not be found.
#0 /Users/work/Dropbox/Websites/cake-cart/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

I've not been able to figure this out. That's all that's in the error logs. A google and/or Stack search shows no-one else has this issue. I'm aware that it's supposed to be straightforward, no API issues.

Anyone shed any light on where I can start solving this?

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1):

Never mind .... for anyone who experiences this, check your version of cake first. I thought mine was 2.2 because I *thought* i had a successful upgrade from 2.1, but it wasn't it was 2.1 still, so I had to go through the migration steps from 2.1 to 2.2 and then 2.3 works perfectly (after closing the browser - even though cache is off, something is cached in the browser I guess)